# Timer Method does not stop execution though it finishes its task

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a windows service that should poll a database for every 5 seconds for the new entries and update the log file.

I am using System.Timers.Timer class to call my Database method and calling Autocancellation for every 5 seconds.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
     try
     {
            ServiceLogFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Autocancellation);
            timer.Interval = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tracktime"]); //number in miliseconds 
            timer.Enabled = true;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
           ServiceLogFile("Error in {OnStart} :" + ex.ToString());
      }
  }

  public void Autocancellation(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
        try
        {
            lock (this)
            {

                //Database accesss
                //select statement 

                //Adding to Data table 
                if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
                {
                    //Update Statements 
                }
                else
                {
                     ServiceLogFile("There is no orders in the table Thread id :" +Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                 }
              }
       }
   }
```

Autocancellation method will be having database access and update statements.

Expected Workflow -

It should update all the entries in the database and return back to the onStart method and poll for every 5 seconds.

Issue -

Whenever it completes updating the rows and if it has time (like if it finishes the updation statement in 2 mins at the last Iteration) and remaining 3 mins it will print "There is no orders in the table". I am not able to stop printing this until it finishes whole its timer.

I tried stopping the timer - But this leads to it will never poll the database again from onStart method.

Here is the sample of logs

When updation starts -

```
Service is stopped at 8/4/2019 1:34:15 PM
Service is started at 8/4/2019 1:34:28 PM
Database check :8/4/2019 1:34:33 PM
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A1
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A2
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A3
```

End of Iteration -

```
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A49997
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A49998
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A49999
{INFO} Cancelled Order {AccessionID} : A50000
Database check :8/4/2019 1:51:53 PM
There is no orders in the table Thread id :4
Database check :8/4/2019 1:51:53 PM
There is no orders in the table Thread id :3
Database check :8/4/2019 1:51:53 PM
There is no orders in the table Thread id :7
```

If we can see the above logs its looping in the same method to print no records. I tried with killing thread and return statements. Nothing worked.

After this Iteration time (5 seconds)
This will be returned to the onStart and polls for 5 seconds correctly and logs are perfect -

```
Database check :8/4/2019 1:52:04 PM
There is no orders in the table Thread id :96
Database check :8/4/2019 1:52:09 PM
There is no orders in the table Thread id :97
Database check :8/4/2019 1:52:14 PM
```

Help in stopping the timer for the running instance and it should poll back as expected.

Comment: So why you have the else statement. Why not handle your update and write at end once to log file?

Comment: Because if there is any break in the Update statement I should print it on the logfile for every iteration.  Lets assume if the database doesn't have new rows to update I need to print else statement. My issue is to break the method execution once every update is being performed.

Comment: Are you using the same lock when modifying the `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the `AutoReset` property to `False` and re-start the timer after there are no more records. The reason for this is your `Autocancellation` might be called multiple times from different threads while you are busy processing the records.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=netframework-4.8):

> Gets or sets a Boolean indicating whether the Timer should raise the
>   Elapsed event only once (false) or repeatedly (true).

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
     try
     {
            ServiceLogFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Autocancellation);
            timer.Interval = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tracktime"]); //number in miliseconds 
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
           ServiceLogFile("Error in {OnStart} :" + ex.ToString());
      }
  }

public void Autocancellation(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        lock (this)
        {

            //Database accesss
            //select statement 

            //Adding to Data table 
            if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                //Update Statements 
            }
            else
            {

                 ServiceLogFile("There is no orders in the table Thread id :" +Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
             }
          }
   }
   finally
   {
// in anycase, start the timer again. In this pattern, you will not get
// any calls until the processing is finished.    
            timer.Start();
       }
    }
```

Comment: So you need the execution of the timer all the time on order to check for the new data. So, in this case -> remove the log file. I think what was happening to you in the first example is that your timer delegate was called multiple times from different threads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could start my thread initially, however, After completing updating my records - it stopped the timer. And i have added some more records to check whether my method gets up to update it. But, Couldn't succeed with updating rows.

Comment: Okay.. I think i need the log file there to print "No records" Because - Lets assume we have some data in the database to update and it did its job for this time. And later (after 5 or 10 seconds) it has to check whether the data is present if so it has to update or log - there is no data at this moment..

Comment: In addition to your answer - Can you please explain me, is it possible to create a single thread for the method that would be called for every interval of a timer?

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will prevent multiple calls to the delegate.

Comment: Sure. Changed my code and kept it for running. I will get back to you in 5 mins. Thanks a lot for mentoring me for this issue.

Comment: It did work. Thank you so much for the code. I have one last concern - Can you please answer it? Can you please explain me, is it possible to create a single thread for the method that would be called for every interval of a timer?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497466/c-sharp-single-threaded-timer